# Android View align bottom (programmatically) without XML

Tags: android, xml, alignment

I got a problem with setting aligning my view programatically to the bottom of the screen. Basically I just want to place my admob advert at the screen bottom. I can't do it with XML because it would be even more troublesome. Right now I already got the advert working, and added it manually to the `RelativeLayout`, but by default it appears at the top of the screen. I tried to use the gravity command, but couldn't get it working.

Here's the code snippet:

```
    _glSurfaceView = new CCGLSurfaceView(this);

    adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "a14e04559caea39");
    adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
    adView.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);

    RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(this);

    rl.addView(_glSurfaceView);
    rl.addView(adView);     

    setContentView(rl);
    adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 37):

dragonfly's answer worked for me.
Here is the complete code snippet for the reference

```
adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
panel = new MySurfaceView(this);

AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);

RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(this);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lay = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

lay.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);

rl.addView(panel);
rl.addView(adView, lay);

setContentView(rl);

adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Comment: what is MySurfaceView? could you eleborate your code to me?

Answer (score 11):

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
 p.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM, tv.getId());
```

Answer (score 9):

Add the advert to the RelativeLayout with LayoutParams as follows:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rparams = (LayoutParams) rl
            .getLayoutParams();
    rparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    ((ViewGroup) rl).addView(adView, rparams);
```

instead of just

```
rl.addView(adView);
```

Good luck! :)

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for the quick answers, but somehow it won't work. I keep getting a nullpointerexception + the app crashes, at the line "addRule".

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe it's because you're creating a RelativeLayout dynamically within the program...if you have a RelativeLayout already defined in an xml file and you refer rl to it by id, it'll work. Good luck anyhow! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    ImageButton buttonAdvance = new ImageButton(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new       RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(160, 160);
    params.leftMargin = 5;
    params.bottomMargin = 4;
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    buttonAdvance.setLayoutParams(params);
```