# How to remove ImageView alignment programmatically?

Tags: android, layout

```
<ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/wipeID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/popup_window"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/linerID"
        android:src="@drawable/wiper_btn"/>
```

In the above one android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/linerID" is remove programmatically how to remove that one?

Comment: not understandable... please will you explain in detail

Comment: Before perform onclick i want these two allignments android:layout_above="@+id/popup_window"
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/linerID" But after perform onclick i need remove the this one android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/linerID" programattically how to do that one plz help me.

Comment: OK.. do you mean to hide some view?

Comment: yes how to do that one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18852423/how-to-show-hide-grouped-views-in-android

Comment: thanku @pragna But i want remove just this one only android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/linerID"  don't hide the total view. I don't know is it possible or not.

Answer (score 1):

If I don't get you wrong you want to change your layout parameters...

So this is roughly how you can achive it:

1. get your imageview with findViewById(...)
2. get the layout parameters somehow like this:
   LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = ( LinearLayout.LayoutParams) imageView.getLayoutParams();
3. change them by setting the values you want:
   params.setMargins(newX, newY, 0, 0); //for margins
   imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
   **if this does not work (param for align bottom does not exist) you can add rules:**
   [this could help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6563163/android-view-align-bottom-programmatically-without-xml) or [google](https://www.google.de/search?q=android%20%20LayoutParams%20alignBottom&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:de:official&client=firefox-a&channel=sb&gfe_rd=cr&ei=f1iMU_-oDYSJ8Qfuq4HoCA#channel=sb&q=android%20%20layout%20params%20add%20rule&rls=org.mozilla:de:official) something like "android add rule layout param"

hope this leads you to the right track...

Answer (score 0):

Try using this :
imageView.setBaselineAlignBottom(false);